# Complex algorithm for generating a BIRT table

Tags: sql, birt

I have a birt dataset containing the following columns, sorted by 'time':

```
devicename   String
operatorname String
time         Date Time
action       String
info         String
```

'action' can have one of four possible values:

```
MAINTENANCE_START
DEVICE_DEFECT
DEVICE_REPAIRED
MAINTENANCE_STOP
```

I want to generate a table in my report using this data. I should have a table entry for each row of the dataset where action has the value 'MAINTENANCE_STOP'. My table should have the following entries:

```
Time
Operator
Status
Duration
Maintenance_Info
```

- 'Time' should take its value from the 'time' column of the last 'MAINTENANCE_START' before the current 'MAINTENANCE_STOP'
- 'Operator' should be the operator who performed the 'MAINTENANCE_START'
- 'Status' - if between the last 'MAINTENANCE_START' and the current 'MAINTENANCE_STOP' there was either a 'DEVICE_DEFECT' or 'DEVICE_REPAIRED' event, this should have the value 'Device not available' else it should be 'Device available'.
- 'Duration' - should be the difference (interval) between the 'MAINTENANCE_STOP' and the last 'MAINTENANCE_START'
- 'Maintenance_Info' - should be a concatenation of all the 'info' strings between the last 'MAINTENANCE_START' and the current 'MAINTENANCE_STOP'.

  This was originally done in a java bean for a web application. In java it wasn't so hard to do, however, in BIRT I am not sure it is even possible. Can you give me any advice on how I can do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have it done in Java, you can leverage that inside BIRT using a Scripted Data Source.  A scripted data source relies on a Java object to build an array of objects, each object will represent a "row" on the data set.  At runtime the BIRT Engine fires off the java object to go build the array and when that is compete the array is read into the data set on the report and you are off and running.

More info on scripted data sources here:  [Scripted Data Source Examples](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/examples/scripting/scripteddatasource/)